# Access Denied Error on IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

i have created a web site on IIS 7.5 which using 91 port on a local server(ip:192.168.0.50) and i am using framework 4.5. When i try to display my web site on browser, html files comes normally but aspx files(which have also sql connenction) doesn't. And it gives error as below. I also gave the Administrator permission to the releated path and when i tested the settings, Authentication and Authorization comes ok. So you guys have any solution? Thanks.

Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access is denied Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is
>   denied

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]

Comment: The error is rather specific, your web application cannot connect to the SQL Server. Check the credentials there, you might have misspelled the server name

Comment: Check the SQL Connection string . replace server name with "./" instead of "./SQLExpress".

Comment: İ described connection string in web config and i am sure it's true, i also tried to give a database connection on web and the result was same. Is there a appilcation pool problem, what do you think about that?

Comment: My app pool has Administrator identity so, it has to connect to sql server, right? Should i do something more on manegement studio or somewhere else?